# How to find all roots of the equation $ x^3 + 2x^2 - 3x$ in $\mathbb Z_{12}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Firstly you can factor it completely from $ x^3 + 2x^2 -3x$, which is $x(x-3)(x+1)$. We have the obvious roots of $0$, $3$ and $-1$, but what about the other roots? I have a little confusion here because of the $\mathbb Z_{12}$ (addition, mod 12).

Is it safe to say that $11$ will also be a root because $11 + 1 = 12$, which equals $0$ in $\mod 12.$

And also, am I only allowed to pick values between $0$ and $11,$ or can I pick any value from the real numbers provided it is congruent to $0$, mod 12?

I have a feeling this has something to do with ring theory, because it's the ring theory section, but I'm not too sure.

Answer (score 3):

You are right 11 is also a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$. You are allowed to pick values not  from 0 to 11, but only integers. However since you are considering solutions in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ you don't need other values besides 0 from 11.

Comment: So is 15 also a root? Because 15-3 = 12 = 0 in Mod Z12? And also, how is this related to rings? Is there some type of theorem relating to rings and factoring?

Comment: @user121615 your reasoning is correct, 15 is a solution, but note that 15=3 in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, because 15-3=12=0 in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$. So in $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$ 15 and 3 are the same root to that polynomial. If you are looking for a reference here is a good book: A first course in abstract algebra by Rotman.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I would love to read that book, but I am a little strapped for time on this one. I appreciate the reference. Do you have any quick online sources I can read about this at? And is there more solutions to this problem than 0,1,3 and -11?

Comment: Oh wait, nvm, I found a good reference. Thanks for the help Studzinski. You were terrific

Comment: great, I searched but didn't find anything to help more. If you liked my answer please accept it.